# Understanding the File System and memory allocation

Tags: filesystem

Some confusion over a warning message saying my root directory is almost full.

What exactly is my root directory, is it synonymous with my home directory, or is it literally the 'root' folder which has 0 items in my File System (see attached).

Also, can anyone explain my disk usage analyzer results for /media/jim ?
I have 2 2TB external drives connected which are far from full yet /media/jim says I am 100% full.

And under  System Monitor - File Systems I see /dev/sdc2 is 94% full.
How do I reclaim this file space?

Thanks for any feedback

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your /  (root) directory is the top-level directory on which all other mounted file-systems are mounted.   If you have a different partition setup for your /home, then it is 'mounted' in / but its space can only be used by files stored in its directories, and it won't use any space in your / (which is everything that doesn't have its own storage/partition).

Comment: Google says, `About 109,000,000 results`

Comment: Better way is to view space distribution for corresponding mount points. You can use *File Systems* tab of `gnome-system-monitor` or `mate-system-monitor`.

Comment: OP. Thanks a bit clearer but still don't know how to reclaim this file space. See my revised question. 
Under  System Monitor - File Systems I see /dev/sdc2 is 94% full.
How do I reclaim this file space? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make space to resize the root (/) partition? No free space on root, cant uninstall software nor update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656554/how-do-i-make-space-to-resize-the-root-partition-no-free-space-on-root-can)